# Recursion and if statement in java

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion

I am implementing recursive Binary Search in Java using ArrayList. Here is my code:

```
public static boolean binarySearchRecursive(List<Integer> list, int item) {
    int midpoint = (list.size()) / 2;
    System.out.println(list.get(midpoint));
    if (list.get(midpoint) == item) {
        return true;
    } else if (list.get(midpoint) > item) {
        binarySearchRecursive(list.subList(0, midpoint), item);
    } else if (list.get(midpoint) < item) {
        binarySearchRecursive(list.subList(midpoint + 1, list.size()), item);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then I call `binarySearchRecursive` providing arguments: ArrayList with size = 1 000 000, where index == value; and item == 64327. 
Console output is:

> ...
>   64241,
>   64317,
>   64355,
>   64336,
>   64327

So I see midpoint got value of item and method should return true after comparation, but method constantly return `false`. What is pecularity of this method? Why code proceeds until last return statment, and return  false from there instead of return true from 5th line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of problems there:

1. You need to *return* the result of your recursive calls. Right now, you're just calling `binarySearchRecursive` and then returning `false` — which is a problem if they found something and returned `true`!

   The *general form* of a recursive function/method is this:

   ```
   ResultType method(data) {
       if (condition_that_ends_recursion) {
           return positive_result;
       }
       return method(new_data_function_should_work_with);
   }
   ```

   Note that when calling itself, `method` returns the result of the recursive call.
2. At some point, you're going to run out of entries to check (e.g., the sublist will be zero), but your code isn't allowing for that, it assumes the list will always have at least one entry. You need to account for that condition as well in your logic.

---

Side note: If you have a `return` in an `if` branch, there's no need to use `else` for the next condition.

Side note 2: You have `if (list.get(midpoint) == item)` and then `else if (list.get(midpoint) > item)`, so there's no need for `else if (list.get(midpoint) < item)`; just `else` is all you need there. If it's not `==`, and it's not `>`, you know for sure it's `<`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to return the result of the callee as the result of the main caller.

```
    public static boolean binarySearchRecursive(List<Integer> list, int item) {
    int midpoint = (list.size()) / 2;
    System.out.println(list.get(midpoint));
    if (list.get(midpoint) == item) {
        return true;
    } else if (list.get(midpoint) > item) {
        **return** binarySearchRecursive(list.subList(0, midpoint), item);
    } else if (list.get(midpoint) < item) {
        **return** binarySearchRecursive(list.subList(midpoint + 1, list.size()), item);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Without these return statements it just returns from the sub method true, but goes to the end main method returns FALSE

Comment: That's *half* the problem. :-)

Comment: your answer very protective and conservative :) I set him free to guess rest of the his errors. He needed to know what is the problem :) New guys need to dig the internet and code much. They ask and want whole bunch of code.

Comment: You'll note I didn't actually code anything for him. :-)

Comment: heyyy that was just copy/past engineering though ! I wasnt coding :) By the way my vote is for you :)